# Css image resize by height, keep aspect ratio and max-width

Tags: css

I've a big image and I want to resize it by height (fixed). Width has to keep the aspect ratio, but I want that only a max-width of the image is shown. Is it possible to do this with a single css div?

Answer (score 0):

Yes put in max-height instead of height